# Missing the X-WC-Store-API-Nonce header. This endpoint requires a valid nonce. Postman Error

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

POST : xyz.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/add-item
I'm Developing a mobile woocommerce application and try to add-item in cart but getting some error please help to fix this problem thanks.

```
In Body:
  
{
"id": "8924",
"quantity":1,
"variation": [
             {
              "items" :{
              "attribute": "hj",
              "value": "knk"
              }
           }
        
           ]
        }

Error:
{
 "code": "woocommerce_rest_missing_nonce",
 "message": "Missing the X-WC-Store-API-Nonce header. This endpoint requires a valid nonce.",
 "data": {
 "status": 401
        }
}
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass back a nonce as a header, previously `X-WC-Store-API-Nonce`, now just `Nonce`.

A nonce is required on all `POST` requests and all requests to `store/checkout`. You can get a nonce on every response you get from the server, so if you hit `store/cart`, you will get a nonce, save that nonce and use it for future requests, but make sure to update it after each response.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing the error is due to API requiring not just any nonce, but a specific one.

Don’t just pass the value return from `wp_create_nonce('my-string')`, the value has to come from `wp_create_nonce('wc_store_api')`

you can read more about it here:

https://digitalapps.com/woocommerce-rest-api-cart-endpoint-error/

Comment: So would this be a value that you generate in `wp_localize_script()` and then include in your Javascript that calls the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable nonce check by adding this filter in your WordPress functions.php file or in a snippet using code snippets plugin

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_store_api_disable_nonce_check', '__return_true' );
```

Comment: This is handy for local testing, but I wouldn't use it in production.